# How do I initialize core data objects

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, initialization

Im very new to CoreData, I had a class that initialized all my objects, set them in an array and used .append from a pickerView array to a TableView array. Of course upon terminating the app the tableview array is cleared. Im trying to now use core data to save but the tableView is now returning every object in my code. How can I choose an object and set it to an array used by the tableView. thanks in advance

SavedRun is my entity

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension SavedRun {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SavedRun> {
    return NSFetchRequest<SavedRun>(entityName: "SavedRun")
}

@NSManaged public var formulaTitle: String?
@NSManaged public var formulaNumber: String?
@NSManaged public var base: String?
@NSManaged public var baseValue: Double
@NSManaged public var vit: String?
@NSManaged public var vitValue: Double
@NSManaged public var min: String?
@NSManaged public var minValue: Double
@NSManaged public var verdNat: String?
@NSManaged public var verdNatValue: Double


}
```

then in my init class.

```
import UIKit

class AllFormulasTest {

var pickerArr = [SavedRun]()
static var tableArr : [SavedRun] = []

init() {

    let F1354670 = SavedRun(context: PersistenceService.context)
    F1354670.formulaNumber = "F1354670"
    F1354670.formulaTitle = "test formula title"
    F1354670.base = "Base name"
    F1354670.baseValue = 251.90
    F1354670.vit = "Vit name"
    F1354670.vitValue = 50.38
    F1354670.min = "Min name"
    F1354670.minValue = 45.34
    F1354670.verdNat = "Verd name"
    F1354670.verdNatValue = 16.79

    // I have about 200  formulas like the one above I use for my work.

    // pickerArr is used for my pickerView then appened to tableArr array of what needs to be made.
    pickerArr = [F1354670, F1354670, F1354670, F1354670, F1354670]
    // pickerArr returns all the ones created (not just 'F1354670') and works great.

    //this array needs to be what is shown on the tableView
    AllFormulas.tableArr = [] as? [SavedRun] ?? []

    // but.. I think doing it this way is acutally saving F1354670 into 'SavedRun'
    // which causes tableArr array to show them aswell 
    }

}
```

how could I go about making the formulas like a data base and not shown in tableArr until chosen from the pickerArr.

thank you in advance.